# How to reserve a global variable name in with vite or rollup? (window.FB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, vite, rollup

I'm trying to setup "login with facebook" functionality in my application.

Everything works great locally or if I don't minify my bundle.

However when I minify my bundle output there is a global function that happens to be minified to `FB` (`window.FB`), which completely breaks the facebook SDK.

Facebook doesn't provide any way to use any other variable name. So I'm trying to figure out how to "reserve" or prevent my bundler viteJS / Rollup minifying this other global function name to `FB`.

The global function that's getting minified comes from nodejs and is likely being imported through some npm package but I am not sure which one. (even if I could find it, I'm using it for a reason and there might not be a good alternative).

This is the random nodejs function that's being saved on the global window and minified to be called "FB":  https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/4b6e4c1eb110e0be671ec5972bf280d2bf3892d8/lib/_stream_readable.js#L497

How can I prevent the `window.FB` global variable name to be taken up by this function? (with minify turned on of course).

I have tried setting `build.outputs.globals.FB` to "TEST", and defining `window.FB` in my index.ts file to see if it would force it to not use the same name for minifcation. But it doesn't seem to affect the bundler.

Answer (score 0):

While working on a custom library that should be used on another website I've managed to achieve this disabling minification In `vite.config.js` file :

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        // your plugins goes here...
    ],
    build: {
        minify: false, // <-- this is the important part
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.tsx'),
            name: 'my-lib',
            fileName: 'lib-file',
            formats: ['umd'] // <-- I used 'umd' here as a precaution measure, to make it possible to use the lib in every browser
        }
    }
});
```